# Replace string with same string Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Using the `re` module, how can I replace a matched string with the same string?

I am using `re.sub()` like so:

```py
> import re

> re.search("Some", "Some string")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='Some'>

> re.sub("Some", r"\1", "Some string")
error: invalid group reference 1 at position 1
```

Why am I getting an error here? I am using `\1` as specified in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) under the `\number` section.

Comment: It is `\g<0>` that refers to the whole match, not `\1` (it only refers to Group 1 value).

Comment: Thank you, `\g<0>` works indeed. I was not understanding matching groups properly.

Comment: You can read a bit more on [regex replacement pattern syntax here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) (general info).